# JFrame pass variable from button click to another class

Tags: java, jframe

Let's say that I have two classes like the ones shown below. In my first class named Product, I have the product instance variables, and in the second class I have my JFrame components. Now I am trying to get the value from JTextField titemName and assign it to setProductName when the button is clicked?

Could someone please give me a hint on how to do it? Until now, I am getting null calue for getWineName being that the setWineName is out of scope I guess?

1st class:

```
public class Wine {
  private String wineName;
  private double winePrice;
  private int wineQnty;

public Wine(String wineName, double winePrice, int wineQnty)
{
    this.wineName = wineName;
    this.winePrice = winePrice;
    this.wineQnty = wineQnty;
}

public Wine()
{
    this ("", 0, 0);
}


// Getters (accessor methods) and setters(modifier methods) 
public String getWineName() {
    return wineName;
}

public void setWineName(String wineName) {
    this.wineName = wineName;
}

public double getWinePrice() {
    return winePrice;
}

public void setWinePrice(double winePrice) {
    this.winePrice = winePrice;
}

public int getWineQnty() {
    return wineQnty;
}

public void setWineQnty(int wineQnty) {
    this.wineQnty = wineQnty;
}

}
```

2nd class:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class LWMGUI extends JFrame
implements ActionListener
{ 
    private Wine wine;
    private CustomerAccount custAcct;
    private JButton psale, preturn;
    private JLabel litemName, litemQuantity, litemPrice, ltransAmount, lcurrBalance; 
    private JTextField titemName, titemQuantity, titemPrice, ttransAmount, tcurrBalance;

public LWMGUI(Wine w, CustomerAccount c)
{
    wine = w;
    custAcct = c;


    // Creating Dialog box to get customer's name
    String custName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the customer name: ");
    if (custName.isEmpty() || custName == null){
        System.exit(0);
    }


    //Creating dialog box to get the current balance for the given customer
    String currBalanceTxt;
    while (true){
         currBalanceTxt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the current balance for this customer: ");

         try {
                Double currBalance = Double.parseDouble(currBalanceTxt);
                break;

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a numeric value!", "Non-numeric value error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
    Double currBalance = Double.parseDouble(currBalanceTxt);

    //Setting customer account values
    c.setAccountName(custName);
    c.setCurrBalance(currBalance);

    setTitle("Lilybank Wine Merchants: " + custAcct.getAccountName());
    setSize(560, 150);
    setLocation(200, 200);

    createTop();
    createButtons();
    createBottom();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);


}

    private void createTop() {
        litemName = new JLabel("Name:");
        litemQuantity = new JLabel("Quantity:");
        litemPrice = new JLabel("Price: £");

        titemName = new JTextField(15);
        titemName.addActionListener(this);
        titemQuantity = new JTextField(6);
        titemQuantity.addActionListener(this);
        titemPrice = new JTextField(7);
        titemPrice.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel topPan = new JPanel();
        topPan.add(litemName);
        topPan.add(titemName);
        topPan.add(litemQuantity);
        topPan.add(titemQuantity);
        topPan.add(litemPrice);
        topPan.add(titemPrice);
        add(topPan, "North");
    }

    private void createBottom() {
        ltransAmount = new JLabel("Amount of Transaction:");
        lcurrBalance = new JLabel("Current balance:");
        ttransAmount = new JTextField(6);
        tcurrBalance = new JTextField(6);
        ttransAmount.setEnabled(false);
        tcurrBalance.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel lowerPan = new JPanel();
        lowerPan.add(ltransAmount);
        lowerPan.add(ttransAmount);
        lowerPan.add(lcurrBalance);
        lowerPan.add(tcurrBalance);
        add(lowerPan, "South");
    }

    private void createButtons() {
        // Setting up buttons
        psale = new JButton("Process Sale");
        preturn = new JButton("Process Return");
        psale.addActionListener(this);
        preturn.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel buttonPan = new JPanel();
        buttonPan.add(psale);
        buttonPan.add(preturn);
        add(buttonPan, "Center");
    }


    private class saleButton implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        if (e.getSource() == psale)
        {

            Wine w = wine;
            CustomerAccount ct = custAcct;

            System.out.println("Sale button pressed!");
            String wName = titemName.getText();
            int wQnty = Integer.parseInt(titemQuantity.getText());
            Double wPrice = Double.parseDouble(titemPrice.getText());

            w.setWineName(wName);
            w.setWineQnty(wQnty);
            w.setWinePrice(wPrice);

            String saleAmount = Double.toString(ct.sale());
            System.out.println(saleAmount);
            ttransAmount.setText(saleAmount);


        }

    }

}
```

3rd class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

public class MainCl {

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    Wine wine = new Wine();
    CustomerAccount cuAcct = new CustomerAccount();
    LWMGUI g = new LWMGUI(wine, cuAcct);

    System.out.println(wine.getWineName());
    System.out.println(wine.getWinePrice());
}
```

}

Comment: If `private class saleButton` is button you are talking about.It's normally return null  because Overrided method is empty!

Comment: Else you need get the "wine.name()" from main class not from "Wine class"

Answer (score 0):

You should replacce line `Product p = new Product();` by `Product p = product;` in `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: if I remove the line, than I get "p cannot be resolved"

Comment: Fixed answer above.

Comment: when I try to do a simple print of the getProductName i still don't get anything.

Comment: Please, post complete code. Provided snippet does not show any GUI.

Comment: There is a multi-threading issue. The GUI is show via `setVisible(true)`. 
This method returns immediately, and all following GUI action are performed on [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). So, you `System.out.println` executes almost immediately, and way before you are able to edit values in GUI and push the button.

Comment: There is no simple answer. For instance, you may add an additional button that will print current value. In any case, as long as you launched any GUI action (e.g. `setVisible`), you have an explicitly multi-threaded application with all pros and cons of it.

Answer (score 0):

Shrotly just tried to work on wine class an you must change your code and in main class remove the 'wine.get....' because wine class is empty or not worked right now! you need print the price or name from action listener method(during work) like this :

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        if (e.getSource() == psale)
        {

            Wine w = wine;


            System.out.println("Sale button pressed!");
            String wName = titemName.getText();
            int wQnty = Integer.parseInt(titemQuantity.getText());
            Double wPrice = Double.parseDouble(titemPrice.getText());

            w.setWineName(wName);
            w.setWineQnty(wQnty);
            w.setWinePrice(wPrice);

            System.out.println("Name of wine : "+ wName +", "+"Quanty : "+ wQnty +", "+"Price : "+ wPrice);


        }

    }

}
```

I hope this help you.Good Luck